# How to remove the currency symbol from product price? (SEO requirement)

Tags: magento-1.9, price, seo

Based on this [link](http://schema.org/price), to follow schema.org formatting, the price must not come with any symblos. How can I remove the currency symbol from price?

Solution:

Thanks for the tips, the SEO solution I applied is

```
<div class="no-display" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">       
   <span itemprop="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), false, false); ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: check this https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-remove-currency-sign-for-price-attribute.html

Comment: I'm wondering why it didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270538/magento-price-formated-but-without-currency-symbol), below code worked for me

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($_yourPriceToFormat, false, false);
```

Comment: You have  to use this on all page where symbol is  showing like list,detail,cart,checkout,and all like order template etc

Comment: I just added to product view page to fix the SEO warning issue

Comment: Do you want to remove only from view page ?

Answer (score 0):

***No need to update your code!*.**

Go to **System->Manage Currency -> Symbols** , add 3 Letter currency code there in the text fields

Even that works with any text that you feeds in.

Answer (score 0):

**After struggling for a long time with this problem I found this fix -**

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()))); ?>">
```

**Just insert that line above this one -**

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price,true,false) ?></span>
```

**All credit goes to -**

https://feedarmy.com/kb/magento-microdata-for-google-shopping/